# How to save a combination of text and image in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I need to save data which is q combination of text and images. For example: "some text" 'image' "some text", and the point is, there is no particular format for this data. The image can be at any part of the sequence with the text before and after it. For example:

[image]

I need to save it in the same sequence as it's defined and retrieve and display in the same sequence and preserve the format; Text as text and Image as image.

I know that we can save image in `byte[]` format but how to save text and image together in single column in database?

Kindly help.

Comment: Why do you need to use a single column? The simplest way would be a text column and a BLOB column for the image. Alternatively save to file and store the path in the database.

Comment: how do I keep the sequence and I wont know how many images will be present , dynamically how can I store them in separate columns?

Comment: Ah ok, can you save the images to file? You could use GUID for the file names, and insert them in the relevant points in the text.

Comment: for this I need to keep files in the server.. I am trying to save in data base..

Comment: It's better to store in 2 columns and then join them together when retrieving them.

Comment: A combination of text and images means rich format. Use html or rtf or some other rich formats to create the content. Then save the content in a varbinary(max) column in a table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert an image to text with Base64, for example:

```
var image = File.ReadAllBytes("image.jpg");

var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
```

And you can convert it back to an image again:

```
var image = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

File.WriteAllBytes("image.jpg", image);
```

You just need to figure out how to split/concatenate your text as a whole...

Answer (score 9):

Regardless of the application and storage technology you need the following pieces in your solution:

- Content Model
- Content Editing
- Content Storage
- Content Rendering
- Content Processing and Indexing

Here I will try to explain more about those building blocks:

- **Content Model** - It's a model of the content. To decide about the content mode based on your requirement, consider these options

  - *Maximum flexibility:* A combination of text and images is considered as a rich content. You can use a markup language like `HTML` or rich text formats like `RTF` as format of the content.
  - *Limited structure:* To have a limited structure, you still can rely on rich content (like `HTML`) and easily validate the content to see if the content is in your desired structure. Also as another option, you can rely on a specific class as a template, having a few properties like `Text1`, `Image`, `Text2` and serialize the class as XML or Binary value.

  Essentially, whatever model type that you choose, you need to convert it to `byte[]` or `string` to store in storage. For example you may have a C# class containing some image and text properties and convert it to XML to store in database. Or you may use HTML as content type. In this case DOM is equivalent to C# model and HTML is like XML for you as representation of Document Object Model.
- **Content Editing** - Depending the to content type which you need, you can create a UI as content editor to allow users to create the content.

  - You can use any *Rich Editor* like an `HTML Editor` or `RichTextBox`.
  - Or you may create just a custom UI using `PictureBox`, `TextBox` and other controls for your custom C# model.
- **Content Storage** - You can store the content as `byte[]` in any blob storage. In SQL Server, it could be [`VARBINARY(MAX)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=sql-server-ver15) or [`NVARCHAR(MAX)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=sql-server-ver15) depending to your requirement.

  For example, if using HTML for content type, you can easily save it in both `VARBINARY(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Also if you used any custom C# model, you can easily convert it into binary or `XML` and save it in `VARBINARY(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.
- **Content Rendering** - Whatever content model that you choose, the content renderer is responsible to render the content to the UI of your application. To render the content, in case of using HTML as content type, you can easily use a `WebBrowser` control. In case of using RTF, you can use `RichTextBox`, in case of a custom class, you can use GDI+ or easily use some `PictureBox`, label and `TextBox` controls.
- **Content Processing and Indexing** - After adding the contents to the storage, you may want to have another thread/process to process the content and extract indexing information. This way you can search in the contents easier and faster. For example for the `HTML` contents while you can easily use string search operation, but for advanced search scenarios and data analytics, you can process the html content to extract more information.

### Content Example - HTML

Here is an example of an HTML content. I've created this content using a simple HTML editor which I've shared its code in this answer:

```html
<h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</h3>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
<ol>
  <li>Consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
  <li>Sed do eiusmod tempor</li>
  <li>Incididunt ut labore et dolore</li>
  <li>magna aliqua.</li>
</ol>
<p><i><u>Ut enim</u>: Ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</i></p>
```

### Content Editor Example - HTML Editor

In this example, I'll show how easily you can create a simple but useful html editor in C# or HTML, however you can use 3rd party HTML editors as well. The HTML example which you see above, is created by my simple HTML editor:

[image]

A basic HTML editor could be a `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`. It supposrt common keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to make the selection bold, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to make the selection italic, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to make the selection underlined, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy selection, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut selection, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the selection, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to insert a link.

To have a better user experience for the HTML editor For a Web Application, you can use the `document` object and use its [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) method and easily run commands like `Bold`, `Italic`, `Underline`, `InsertOrderedList`, `InsertUnorderedList`, `InsertImage`, `FormatBlock`, `ForeColor`, `BackColor`, and etc.

Here I will share an example for a C# application and will show you easily you can implement an HTML editor:

```
public class HtmlEditor
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser;
    private dynamic doc;
    private dynamic contentDiv;
    public HtmlEditor(WebBrowser webBrowserControl, string htmlContent)
    {
        webBrowser = webBrowserControl;
        webBrowser.DocumentText = @"<div contenteditable=""true""></div>";
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            doc = webBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
            contentDiv = doc.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
            contentDiv.innerHtml = htmlContent;
        };
    }
    public string HtmlContent => contentDiv.InnerHtml;
    public void Bold() { doc.execCommand("bold", false, null); }
    public void Italic() { doc.execCommand("italic", false, null); }
    public void Underline() { doc.execCommand("underline", false, null); }
    public void OrderedList() { doc.execCommand("insertOrderedList", false, null); }
    public void UnorderedList() { doc.execCommand("insertUnOrderedList", false, null); }
    public void ForeColor(Color color)
    {
        doc.execCommand("foreColor", false, ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color));
    }
    public void BackColor(Color color)
    {
        doc.execCommand("backColor", false, ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color));
    }
    public void InsertImage(Image image)
    {
        var bytes = (byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
        var src = $"data:image/png;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)}";
        doc.execCommand("insertImage", false, src);
    }
    public void Heading(Headings heading)
    {
        doc.execCommand("formatBlock", false, $"<{heading}>");
    }
    public enum Headings { H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6 }
}
```

To use this HTML Editor class, it's enough to have a `WebBrowser` control on a `Form` and initialize the editor this way:

```
HtmlEditor editor;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var html = @"Some html content";
    editor = new HtmlEditor(webBrowser1, html);
}
```

Then you can use a `ToolStrip` to show available commands and run the commands. For example:

```
private void OrderedListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    editor.OrderedList();
}

private void ImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        ofd.Filter = "Image files|*.png;*.jpg;*.gif;*.jpeg;*.bmp";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName))
            {
                editor.InsertImage(image);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If for any reason you need parsing the HTML content, you can rely on HTML Agility Pack library.

Comment: I guess with this model its hard to retrieve back the image/text sequence once its converted to that format

Comment: @NitinSawant, In fact it's not hard at all, but consider the following points: **(1)** Sometime what is important, is just the content, not distinguishing between text and image. Imagine an online test designer or a documentation system as an example. In such system the purpose is being able to design a combination of text and images and store them, also being able to retrieve the stored data as it was designed and show on the screen. In these kind of systems, you usually don't need to distinguish between text and image, you just need to be able to design rich content and show rich content.

Comment: **(2)** Also if distinguishing between the images and texts is important, it's really easy with this structure. images are in `<img>` tag and libraries like HTML Agility pack will help you to easily parse the HTML.

Comment: **(3)** Don't miss the *Indexing and Processing* part in the answer.

Comment: @NitinSawant You also should consider another point as well. HTML content in as example (though a very good one) and as it's already mentioned in the *Content Model* part of the answer, the developer can decide to use even a POCO as model and save it as XML or binary in DB. But keep in mind, the POCO is equal to DOM and the XML is equal to HTML .

Comment: Hi @RezaAghaei , thanks for the detailed post. I could learn about html editor from your post.

Comment: @Naveenkumar You're welcome. In fact the post is not limited to the HTML editor and just shares it as an example. For example you can see how in the code I have converted the image to base64 string as well. It also shares the building block of the application which you are trying to create. Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 5):

Probably this article on Storing Serialized data to SQL will Help you.

http://aspalliance.com/1093_Serialization_in_Database.a[^]

You could make one class with Image and String and make it [Serializable] and insert this serialized data as performed with article link.

and retrieve and cast that serialized data back to original class.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, is there a way to dynamically generate properties of this class as number of strings and number of images are not constant and how to save their sequence?

Answer (score 3):

Saving Text and Image into a *single column* - both as text - sounds like a terrible idea. As [Kai Hartman said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59100720/1501497), there is Base64 encoding. Indeed [HTML itself has a way to inline Images in base64 Format](https://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html). But this process is frowned upon.

For HTML it blows the html size up massively. Wich also makes stuff like Virus scanning the HTML nearly impossible/way to long. Also it massively increases transmission times and prevents features like [image interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps)) from working at all. HTML is expected to only be text, with Bulk data like Images comming across in a seperate request.

Every once in a while someone will try to get around the "external images of HTML mails are not dispalyed" rule for their newsletter - by putting those images in inline. Only to learn the hard way, that Outlook tends to treat inline images as attachments. And/or run head-first in the Email Size limits. Or having to deal with suddenly mass mailing Mails in the MiB size. Then there is stuff like the storage limits for DB Columns, wich are easily filled with inline images. Nevermind if you have to actually *edit* the dang image.

I have 1 standing advice: Never use string if you can avoid it! String is arguably the 2nd worst data format to work with. The only thing worse is raw binary. You can not really avoid it with XML, JSON and the like, but those at least help you deal with that. You should never have XML, Base64 or similar encodings of data in a TextField. The only exception is if you have to store XML explicitly and just parsing/re-creating it is unfeasible.

I feel the need to stress this: Keep data and text appart. In seperate Columns. There is [standing advice never to put important Data into a string property](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET#Don%27tputimportantexceptioninformationontheMessagefield8) - make a seperate property for it. This applies even more so for Databases - make seperate Columns for that. Possibly even a completely seperate *table*, that you only FK reference between the 2 Text columns.

Usually you want to defer the loading of said images till later (at least 1 page of text is shown, or the like). For WebServers that basically means only sending a URL to the Client. And have the inevitable request for the image be handeled by a [HTTP Handler retreiving the stuff for that 1 Image from the DB](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/working-with-image-in-httphandler/), as it is read. Stuff like the images primary Key will do nicely for that.

Note that depending on what you are actually doing here - like a full on Word Processor, Document Viewer or Content Management System - even this advise would become half-worthless. Developing that kind of stuff is a totally different mater then what you showed us here.

Comment: I agree that storing images as data uri may have some side effects. But in general, HTML or data uri images are just example of how the model could be serialized. One may decide to store all model in a single blob, one may decide to store model definition to a blob and images in different blobs and just keep pointers of those images in model definition. These are just different variation of model storage/serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a table `Pages` containing the main reference and metadata of your items with an Id column and a related table to store the assets you want to save for each page, like:

Assets:

- Id int, not null (PK)
- PageId int, not null (FK to Pages table),
- TextData Text, null(contains your text in case of textual value),
- BinaryData varbinary(MAX), null (contains your image data in case of binary value),
- OrderField int, not null (permits saving the sequence information)

So you could retrieve the complete "page" data of "page 1" by calling:

`SELECT * FROM Assets WHERE PageId = 1 ORDER BY OrderField`

You could of course save assets as well in two dedicated tables, one for images and one for strings.

The idea in any case is to keep the binary data separated from the strings and be able to store assets individually, searchable and orderable. Another advantage is that you could save additional metadata in the Assets table adding columns for Filename, Filesize, Alt-Text, etc.